# Clojure Java interop memory model

Tags: memory-management, clojure, jvm

How does Clojure's memory model work for Java interop? Does the JVM use Clojure's persistent memory model when running Java library functions, or are the results of Java functions coerced into persistent values upon returning?

Answer (score 1):

Clojure's persistent memory model is a construct of linguistic constraints and a library of immutable data structures (implemented in Java). It doesn't work for Java interop.

- The JVM is unaware of it.
- The results of Java functions are returned as is.

Java interop is designed to give you direct access to as much of Java as you need, working in the Java way. You can easily use it to bust the Clojure persistent memory model. For example ...

```
=>(let [arr (double-array (range 5))]
    (aset-double arr 3 45.2) arr)
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 45.2, 4.0]
```

You can't do Clojure things to Java arrays

```
=> (assoc (to-array (range 5)) 2 67.4)
ClassCastException [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Associative  clojure.lang.RT.assoc (RT.java:702)
```

or Java things to Clojure arrays

```
=> (aset (vec (range 5)) 2 67.4)
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: aset clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:80)
```

If you try the assigment in Java, I think you'll get an `UnsupportedOperationException` at run time.